# Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder... android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hc2BsawKmRoXsLhAuBlhNFLx_9zlEiWC

My app activity consists of scrollable tablayout, viewpager and recyclerview.
The first load, all the recyclerview in all viewpager works smoothly.
The problem is when i scrolled the 3th or 4th viewpager recyclerview, then i swipe back to 2nd viewpager, i just touch at the recyclerview list, it crashed.
Please help me...

```
    //Connect with tab and viewpager IN ACTIVITY
    TabLayout tabLayout =(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.delivery_tabs);
    ViewPager viewPager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.deliveryviewpager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

    DeliveryTabsPager deliveryTabsPager = new DeliveryTabsPager(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(deliveryTabsPager);
    int page = getIntent().getIntExtra("One", defaultValue);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);


        //IN FRAGMENTS
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapter = new DeliveryListAdapter(getActivity(), searchResults);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


//ViewPagerAdapter
private String titles[]=new String[]{"OUT FOR DELIVERY","INCOMPLETE","COMPLETED","All"};

public DeliveryTabsPager(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    return titles[position];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){

        case 0:
            OFDFragment ofdFragment = new OFDFragment();
            return ofdFragment;
        case 1:
            IncompleteFragment incompleteFragment = new IncompleteFragment();
            return incompleteFragment;
        case 2:
            CompletedFragment completedFragment = new CompletedFragment();
            return completedFragment;
        case 3:
            AllFragment allFragment = new AllFragment();
            return allFragment;
        default:
            return null;

    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}


@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            OFDFragment ofdFragment = new OFDFragment();
        case 1:
            IncompleteFragment incompleteFragment = new IncompleteFragment();
        case 2:
            CompletedFragment completedFragment = new CompletedFragment();
        case 3:
            AllFragment allFragment = new AllFragment();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}
```

The Error massage in RUN

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{68b0359 position=4 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{387a36d VFED.VC.. ........ 0,0-1080,1428 #7f090009 app:id/DispatchAllrecyclerview}, adapter:com.example.guanlee.xenddriverdemo.Adapter.DeliveryListAdapter@7d9fba2, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@3c7b033, context:com.example.guanlee.xenddriverdemo.Activity.ActDeliveryMenu@46f9476
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5421)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5603)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27993 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```